# Clearing the JavaClassPath at Runtime in JLink

Tags: java

I am trying to access a remote MongoDB database through Mathematica using JLink. The connection is fine, but my installation of Mathematica 10.0 seems to contain an SLF4J logger addon, which prints messages like this one:

> 06:33:36.274 [cluster-ClusterId{value='580de2cbdd207b8caf38bb00', description='null'}-###.###.###.###:#####] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Updating cluster description to  {type=STANDALONE, servers=[{address=###.###.###.###:#####, type=STANDALONE, roundTripTime=4.3 ms, state=CONNECTED}]

every few seconds. I would like to get rid of these logger messages by clearing the default ClassPath and only specifying the necessary .jar files.

I tried this using:

```
ReinstallJava[ClassPath -> "~/path_to_my_jar_files"];
```

But according to the output of JavaClassPath[], this seems to only append my path to the default ClassPath, which is

> {/shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Java/, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Java/WolframSSHKeyGen.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Java/WolframSSH.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Autoload/PacletManager/Java/, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Autoload/PacletManager/Java/antlr.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Autoload/PacletManager/Java/mexpr.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Autoload/PacletManager/Java/PacletManager.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Autoload/PacletManager/Java/WRIjdbm.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Autoload/PacletManager/Java/mexprparser.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/poi-scratchpad-3.8-20120326.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/Exif.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/prefsAll.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/resourcesOptional.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/commons-lang-2.1.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/commons-httpclient-3.0.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/stax-api-1.0.1.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/jxl.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/jdbf.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/jackcess-1.1.18.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/zxing-client.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/core-3.0.0.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/ldap.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/poi-3.8-20120326.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-20120326.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/jmf.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/commons-codec-1.3.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/poi-excelant-3.8-20120326.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/tar.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/tagsoup-1.0rc9.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/activation.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/mail.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/poi-ooxml-3.8-20120326.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/customizer.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/jdom.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/Convert.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/javase-3.0.0.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/multiplayer.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/grib-8.0.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/JPEG2000b.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/bzip2.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/xercesImpl.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/externalservice.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/poi-examples-3.8-20120326.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/xml-apis.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/netcdf-4.2.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/mediaplayer.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/JSON.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/commons-collections-3.2.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/gnu-regexp-1.1.4.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/AddOns/Packages/GUIKit/Java/, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/AddOns/Packages/GUIKit/Java/xmlParserAPIs.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/AddOns/Packages/GUIKit/Java/bsf.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/AddOns/Packages/GUIKit/Java/OculusLayout.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/AddOns/Packages/GUIKit/Java/concurrent.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/AddOns/Packages/GUIKit/Java/GUIKit.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/AddOns/Packages/GUIKit/Java/diva-canvas-core.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/AddOns/Packages/GUIKit/Java/bsf-Wolfram.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/AddOns/Packages/GUIKit/Java/xercesImpl.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Links/DatabaseLink/Java/, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Links/DatabaseLink/Java/derbyclient.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Links/DatabaseLink/Java/postgresql-9.3-1100.jdbc4.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Links/DatabaseLink/Java/commons-dbcp-1.2.1.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Links/DatabaseLink/Java/jtds-1.3.1.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Links/DatabaseLink/Java/sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Links/DatabaseLink/Java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Links/DatabaseLink/Java/hsqldb.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Links/DatabaseLink/Java/jaybird-full-2.2.3.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Links/DatabaseLink/Java/commons-pool-1.2.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Links/DatabaseLink/Java/derby.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Links/DatabaseLink/Java/commons-collections-3.1.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Links/DatabaseLink/Java/glazedlists.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Links/DatabaseLink/Java/h2-1.3.174.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Links/RLink/Java/, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Links/RLink/Java/JRIEngine.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Links/RLink/Java/JRI.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Links/RLink/Java/RLink.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Links/RLink/Java/jna.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Links/RLink/Java/REngine.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Links/RLink/Java/log4j-1.2.16.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Links/WebServices/Java/, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Links/WebServices/Java/junit-3.8.1.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Links/WebServices/Java/commons-httpclient-3.0.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Links/WebServices/Java/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Links/XMLSchema/Java/, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Links/XMLSchema/Java/commons-codec-1.3.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/AddOns/Applications/ClusterIntegration/Java/, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/AddOns/Applications/ClusterIntegration/Java/Wolfram_SGE.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/AddOns/Applications/DocumentationSearch/Java/, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/AddOns/Applications/LightweightGridClient/Java/, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/AddOns/Applications/LightweightGridClient/Java/wolfram-remote-services-client.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Components/Interpreter/Java/, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Components/Interpreter/Java/ParseTelephoneNumber.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Components/Interpreter/Java/libphonenumber-6.1.jar, /shared/apps/mathematica/mathematica_10/INSTALL/SystemFiles/Java/Linux-x86-64/lib/tools.jar}

I then tried:

```
ReinstallJava[ClassPath -> None];
AddToClassPath["~/path_to_my_jar_files"];
```

But again, according to the output of JavaClassPath[], this seems to only append my path to the default ClassPath.

Is there any way to completely clear the default JavaClassPath to get rid of this bothersome logger? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

It turns out that `path_to_jar_files` has to be *prepended* to the Java class path. I also had to set the maximum Java heap size to 32 Gb.

The solution looks like this:

`MongoDBJarDirectory=DirectoryName["path_to_jar_files"];
SetOptions[ReinstallJava, JVMArguments->"-Xmx32g"];
ReinstallJava[];
AddToClassPath[MongoDBJarDirectory,"Prepend"->True];`

Answer (score 2):

I use

```
ReinstallJava[CommandLine -> DIRJAVA, ClassPath -> DIRBOTA];
```

where DIRJAVA is the directory of **a JRE I installed myself**, and DIRBOTA is the directory of the Java .jar package I am using.

Comment: Thank you! I think this could work as well.